# Problems when testing (whilst using javascript & QUnit)

Tags: javascript, function, testing, qunit

Given the following code, I have managed to write a test by making use of QUnit for the first part but was unable to test finder.doRoutefinding.  How can I 'mock'the function finder.doRoutefinding? (Mockjax cannot be used here since no ajax calls are involved)

```
    `finder.doSelectDestination = function(address)
    {
        finder.destination = address;
        finder.doRoutefinding(
                finder.departure,
                finder.destination,
                finder.whenRouteLoaded,
                finder.showRoute);
    }

test('Destination Selector',
    function()
    {
        address="London";
        finder.doSelectDestination(address);

        equal(pathfinder.destination,address,  "Succesful Destination Selection");

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are caveats, but you could simply replace the function with your mock:

```
var originalDoRoutefinding = finder.doRoutefinding;
finder.doRoutefinding = function() {
    // Mock code here.
};
// Test code here.
finder.doRoutefinding = originalDoRoutefinding;
```

If that kind of thing works for you, you might consider using a library like [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/).